# Django-rest-auth basic authorization error {"password":["(This field is required"]}

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-rest-auth

I i am new to django-rest-auth and apis. 
Its the first time i build a rest auth and i am not very familiar with Authorization headers and Content Types.

I am trying to understand why when i try to authenticate a user in `/login/` with Basic Authorization like this:

```
curl -X POST -H "Authorization: Basic dXNlcm5hbWU6cGFzc3dvcmQ=" 'https://myurl.com/rest-auth/login/' --insecure
```

i got this error message:

> {"password":["(This field is required"]}

When passing the username and password in the body like this:

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" -d 'username=myuser&password=mypassword' 'https://myurl.com/rest-auth/login/' --insecure
```

I got the key:

> {"key":"b5c0f3a9c7b2fc2f58a74b25f816e2968c64712f"}

Why this is happening?

I also wonder why when trying the same in `/user/` it didn't throw me any error and give me my user model serialized

```
curl -X GET -H "Authorization: Basic dXNlcm5hbWU6cGFzc3dvcmQ=" -H "Cache-Control: no-cache" 'https://myurl.com/rest-auth/user/' --insecure
```

The only difference i can understand is that in `/login` i am using POST and in `/user/` is GET

Can anybody explain this to me?

Thanks for reading!

Answer (score 1):

The '/auth/login/' endpoint is specifically for getting an authentication token to use with token authentication on the rest of the app. It doesn't itself support any authentication methods. The second `curl` command uses the correct method. the third `curl` command works because you are using an endpoint which does support Basic Authentication (you can could also use the token you got in the second call).

Answer (score 1):

pls [refer](https://slurm.schedmd.com/SLUG19/REST_API.pdf)
Inet Mode Example (unprivileged user with AltAuth)

```sh
$ echo -e "GET http://localhost/slurm/v1/diag HTTP/1.1\r\nAccept: */*\r\n" |
slurmrestd -f etc/slurm.token.conf
● slurmrestd: operations_router: /slurm/v1/diag for pipe:[1052487]
● HTTP/1.1 200 OK
● Content-Length: 973
● {
● "parts_packedg": 1,
● "req_timeg": 1568051342,
● "req_time_startg": 1568050812,
● "server_thread_count": 3,
… JSON continues ...
```